# dispatch_async内での参照について

Tags: swift

swift
C＋＋クラスを動かすためのObje-C＋＋
C＋＋(拡張子はmm)

上記のクラスがある状態で、
swift→Obje-C++→C++→Obje-C++→swiftの流れで処理させようとしています。

swiftからは

```
   private var queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("test.test.testcall", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
   dispatch_async(queue, {
      // Obje-C++のクラスのメソッドを呼び出す
   })
```

C＋＋の処理結果をObje-C++から下記のような形で通知を行い、

```
        NSData* info = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void*)info length: sizeof(info)];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"info": info,
                              @"data1":[NSNumber numberWithInt: data1],
                              @"data2":[NSNumber numberWithInt: data2]};
        NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName: @"testNotification" object: nil userInfo: dictionary];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification: notification];
```

swift側で以下のような形で処理をしています。

```
  private var queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("test.test.test", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
   @objc private func testNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        dispatch_async(queue, {
            guard let info = notification.userInfo?["info"] as? NSData else {
                return
            }
            guard let data1 = notification.userInfo?["data1"] as? NSNumber else {
                return
            }
            guard let data2 = notification.userInfo?["data2"] as? NSNumber else {
                return
            }

        // 処理
        })

    }
```

動いてはいるのですが、処理を繰り返すと、
最後のswiftの通知の受信箇所で取り出した中身が空だったりしてしまいます。

そこで、わからなくなってきてしまったのですが、testNotification()の
dispatch_async()内でパラメータnotificationを参照していますが、
これはtestNotification()で渡ってきた値のコピー？を参照している認識なのですがあっているのでしょうか・・・
testNotification()が複数回呼ばれた場合もキューにはそれぞれのnotificationのコピーが渡るので、正しく参照できる！
と考えているのですが、認識違いでしょうか。
dispatch_async(queue, {
   /// ここで参照
})

Comment: 「渡ってきた値のコピー？を参照している認識なのですがあっているのでしょうか」→この部分の認識は間違っているんですが、「正しく参照できる！」ことに変わりはありません。「通知の受信箇所で取り出した中身が空」についてですが、これは`info`, `data1`, `data2`のどれかが`nil`になっている、と言うことでしょうか?もしそうだとすると、あなたが質問中に示されていない部分を「普通ならこうだろう」と言う推測で補間すると**ありえません。** つまり省略された部分で普通じゃないことをしている可能性が高いです。(iOSとかSwiftのややこしいバグを踏み当てた可能性もありますが…。)Objective-C++コードのもう少し正確な内容 (`info`が2種類あるのが解せません)とSwiftでaddObserverしている部分のコードをお示しいただけるでしょうか。

Comment: コメントあるりがとうございます！
やはり参照は正しくできるのですね。
値が空であったり、アクセスエラーやアボートで落ちることもあり、なんとなくメモリ破壊している気がします。
しかもアクセスエラーが発生する箇所がまちまちで苦しい…
つたない質問におつきありくださり本当にありがとうございます。
「dispatch_async内での参照について」は正しく参照できるということで、いちどFIXさせていただきたいと思います！

Comment: testNotification()のdispatch_async()前で、一旦、NSDataのを設定しなおしたところ、取得できるようになりました。（・・・と思います。必ずおこっていたわけではないのでまだ完全に起きない！と言えないのが残念ですが・・・）